# widget size on android tablets honeycomb

Tags: android, android-widget, android-3.0-honeycomb

I have a widget whose min size is 250dp x 180 dp following [android widget size 
design guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html). This should take 4*3 cells. It's working well on phones with gingerbread and ice cream sandwich but when adding my widget on honeycomb I see it occupy only 3*2 cells and my widget isn't completely visible.

**Update** when making the widget resizable it appears good after manually resizing it, but the problem now is with the initial dimensions.

Is there any thing I am missing?

Comment: no not yet, I think I am still missing something

Answer (score 1):

@mmohab
try using old formula
width_of_widget = (numrows* 74) - 2
height_of_widget = (numcols* 74) - 2
on my samsung tab using new formula(70 × n − 30), 4x2 was appearing 3x2.
only after using old formula. Widget size on my samsung tab came as expected - 4x2